# After each launch, Chrome takes ~4 minutes’ delay to visit the first page

Tags: google-chrome, proxy

Using Windows 10, but I have had this issue in Windows 8.1 too.

Starting yesterday, out of nowhere, Chrome started to take ~4 minute to be able to navigate to any web page for the first time. After the 1st time of navigation, the subsequent page visits are fine even in a new tab.
When I close chrome, and start again, the first time navigation ~4 min delay starts again.

- IE works perfectly fine.
- Firefox works perfectly fine
- Important to consider that only chrome shows this symptom!!!

I installed chrome a few months ago and chrome is in Auto update, so I expect I have the latest version of chrome. The version is Version 47.0.2526.73 m.

I researched, and many people suggest to reset the IP stack or change the network card metric priorities. I exhausted those options and they did not help. The problem arises only with Chrome anyway.

**Important Clue: Same type of delay when Chrome tries to open "Internet Properties" dialog box:**

I found a clue that I believe it should help to find the root cause of the issue:

I noticed that when I go to Settings->Show advanced settings->Click on the “Change Proxy settings”. The dialog takes the same amount of delay ~4 time for the 1st time. That means nothing works until chrome is able to pop the “Change Proxy settings” dialog. The issue with the “Internet Settings” popup is with Chrome only.

- The command line inetcpl.cpl pops the same dialog box instantly and
  snappy!
- IE->Tools->Internet options pops the same dialog box snappy
- Control Panne->Internet Option pops the same dialog vary fast

Only and Only With [Chrome-> Settings->Show advanced settings->Click on the “Change Proxy settings”] takes long time (~4 min) to pop the dialog, and I am not able to visit any page until this dialog pops up

What is the root of this problem?

Any help would be appreciate